# wxPython StyledTextCtrl Set (Partial) Text Color

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets, textcolor, wxstyledtextctrl

How to set text color in a StyledTextCtrl, but only some word? I mean let's say I have

Lucy is Blue

and I want **only** the word 'Blue' to be colored Blue

Answer (score 1):

See the wxPython demo for the StyledTextCtrl. It shows how to do this exact thing. I think the bit you're looking for is something like this:

```
ed.StartStyling(190, 0xff)
ed.SetStyling(20, 2)
```

Where 190 is the 190th character and you set the style for the next 20 characters.

Comment: You forgot about setting style (number 2 in your example) first: StyleSetSpec(2, "fore:#0000ff")

Comment: Well, that's in the demo example code too. I just didn't notice / include it.

Comment: what is 0xff in ed.StartStyling(190, 0xff)?

Answer (score 0):

To change the style of a line, you have to get the position of the first byte and the ending byte. then, you can define a Style (StyleSetSpec) that you make start at the first byte (StartStyling) and that you apply on the whole line (SetStyling). You have to re-apply the default style (0) at the ending byte. Here is my code:

```
# Move to line
self.editname.GotoLine(line-1)
# Get position
pos = self.editname.GetCurrentPos()
# Define style 4
self.editname.StyleSetSpec(4, "back:#ff0000")
# Starts style at position pos
self.editname.StartStyling(pos, 0xffff)
# Until posend position, apply style 4
self.editname.SetStyling(posend-pos, 4)
# Restore style 0 after the ending byte of the line
self.editname.SetStyling(posend, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this where text_area is a StyledCtrlText

```
self.text_area.StyleSetSpec(stc.STC_P_DEFAULT,"fore:#FF0000")
```

next put the text you want to change color